# How can I re-authenticate StackAlert Addon

Tags: support, stackauth, authentication, oauth2

Recently I removed **StackAlert** Firefox addon from my **apps** list in **StackExchange**. Now when I reinstall it, it is not authenticating and giving message

**`key` is not valid for passed `access_token`..**

How can I get rid of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

I found answer myself and posted in my blog post  [StackAlert Firefox Extension error key is not valid for passed access_token](http://techierg.blogspot.com/2013/03/stackalert-firefox-extension-error-key.html)

**Solution in brief**

When you remove the application from **StackExchange** apps, and even after uninstalling the extension from **Firefox**, you will still have traces of that extension in **Firefox**.

To make this extension work again, we have edit **Firefox configuration** using `about:config`.

In that, reset the following settings which makes the extension work again.

1. `extensions.stackalert.access_token`
2. `extensions.stackalert.error_details`
3. `extensions.stackalert.inbox_contents`